# Is exporting CSV with aws_s3.query_export_to_s3 better than java query stream results to s3 bucket?

Tags: java, spring, export, amazon-rds, export-to-csv

Help.

Here's the situation...

- The Postgres server is hosted in AWS, it holds a large amount of data.
- The CSV file would contain several calculated fields

Question:

- Is exporting data to a CSV file using aws_s3.query_export_to_s3 better than using the traditional java query stream results to s3 bucket? Anyone? What is your opinion on this?

Thank you in advance for your help and reply.